# compare a variable having file name with an array having Sharepoint farm solution names

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I have a variable containing a wsp file name. Examle: `$wspfile="abc.wsp"`

I have an array which stores all the SharePoint farm solutions. I need to compare this wsp file in the array, and if it is present I need to take a backup of this solution to local. I am new to PowerShell.

Please give some suggestions.

```
$wspfile="abc.wsp";
[string[]]$FarmSolutions = Get-SPSolution; 

for ($i=0; $i -lt $FarmSolutions.length; $i++) 
{
    if($FarmSolutions[i] -Match $wspfile) 
    { 
        $farm = Get-SPFarm;
        $file = $farm.Solutions.Item("abc.wsp").SolutionFile; 
        $file.SaveAs("E:\abc.wsp");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And wrap it up in a try catch block something like this:

```
try
{
  $farm = Get-SPFarm;
  $file = $farm.Solutions.Item("abc.wsp").SolutionFile;
  $file.SaveAs("E:\abc.wsp")
}
catch
{ 
  "Solution not found"
}
```